# How to add images to a carousel by storing images in a php variable through a get_field function and echoing the image src inside item class?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, variables, echo, carousel

Instead of directly posting the src of the image inside class="item". 
How can one echo out images using only one item class, that are acquired from a get_field function without repetition. I have 5 images that are fetched through get_field that are being stored in $image.

```
$image = get_field('field-name', $post->ID);


<div class="carousel slide" id="leader" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Im assuming your using ACF with WordPress?

Comment: @danjbh Yes, I am.